# Change property of element when hovering over another element

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to change a property of one element when hovering over another. In this case it is in my navigation.

What I have is a sub menu with a .class of .sub-menu

When I hover over the sub menu I want the parent of that element to change background color

The HTML code

```
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li id"menu-item-1"><a>HOME</a></li>
  <li id"menu-item-2"><a>About</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a>Some Link</a></li>
     </ul></li>
  <li id"menu-item-3"><a>Services</a></li>
 </ul>
```

So what I am trying to do is when I hover over the Sub Menu, I want the About Link to have a background-color.

The CSS code I been trying :

```
.sub-menu a:hover + #menu-item-2 a{
   background-color:#FF0;
 }
```

Also tried both of these:

```
.sub-menu a:hover ~ #menu-item-2 a{
   background-color:#FF0;
 }

.sub-menu a:hover > #menu-item-2 a{
   background-color:#FF0;
 }
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction here.

You can see the problem I have here - http://switchmedialab.co.za/switch-media/

When I hover over the service the background image "splat" appears but when I hover over the sub nav it disappear. I need it to stay there for the hover state.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript in this condition, it will be good,

```
<ul class="main-nav" id="mainDiv">
  <li id"menu-item-1"><a>HOME</a></li>
  <li id"menu-item-2"><a>About</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu" onmouseover="colourChange()";>
       <li><a>Some Link</a></li>
     </ul></li>
  <li id"menu-item-3"><a>Services</a></li>
 </ul>
```

javascript,

```
<script>
function colourChange() {
  document.getElementById("mainDiv").style.backgroundColor="#FF0";
}
</script>
```

same thing you can do in CSS also. Like this,

```
.sub-menu:hover + .main-nav {
    background: ##FF0
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes make sense. Is there no other way with just CSS?

Comment: I have added the CSS code also, I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can not influence a parent depending on state of child

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/AdKP9/

```
#menu-item-2:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

---

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/AdKP9/1/

just add

```
.sub-menu:hover {
   background: white; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks but wont work as we are changing both elements background colour in this case. I only want the #menu-item-2 background to change when I hover over the .sub-menu a. and only the #menu-item-2 must change, not both.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are influence the parent-child concept. try this

```
#menu-item-2 a:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks but wont work as we are changing both elements background colour in this case. I only want the #menu-item-2 background to change when I hover over the .sub-menu a. and only the #menu-item-2 must change, not both.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
:target
{

background-color: #e5eecc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="main-nav" id="mainDiv">
  <li id"menu-item-1"><a>HOME</a></li>
  <li id="news1"><a href="#news2">About</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu" onmouseover="colourChange()";>
       <li><a href="#news1">Some Link</a></li>
     </ul></li>
  <li id"menu-item-3"><a>Services</a></li>
 </ul>

</body>
</html>
I tried to use CSS3 since you wanted it to be CSS else Javascript is the best in this case.
```